# problem with shading node, I don't know how to apply another texture

Tags: materials

I'm working on a project with material of blender. Since this morning, I tried to apply a texure where i can paint with, above another texture with brick. I want to be able to paint above the brick texture. I can't paint from the brick texture because on the shading node are applied color nodes that modify the base color of the brick.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect your textures to a *Mix* node with a mask image as the factor as shown below. Wherever you paint white, Texture 2 will show up, and wherever you paint black, Texture 1 will show up.

[image]

I suggest to use the MatLayer free add-on. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-fT5MXs5ds) is the YouTube video that explains how to use it, and you can get it from this [GitHub page](https://github.com/LoganFairbairn/matlayer).

Answer (score 0):

You can mix your current node setting with an *Image Texture* that is transparent, through a *Color > Mix Color* in *Multiply* mode (or *Mix* mode, depending on how you want the images to mix), plug the *Alpha* output of the new image into the *Factor* of the *Mix Color*:

[image]